# SQL Server CE in a multi user scenario - is this really, really stupid?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am trying to use SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 as a database backend for a sales application. There would be 3-4 installations of a Windows Forms application which would all (via LINQ2SQL) read from and write to one .sdf file located on a network share.

My (pretty inextensive) testing has shown that this could be viable. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645984.aspx) states that SQL Server CE supports up to 256 connections. [Does SQL Server CE even lock its rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342358/sql-server-ce-addin-read-and-write-collision-avoidance) Are there other concurrency issues that I should worry about?

Bottom line is, has anyone used SQL Server CE successfully with multiple applications connecting to same database?

Should I spare myself future headaches and go with SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MS recommends (from Darian Miller's [comparison guide](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc)):

> When you require data service
>   functionality, such as the ability to
>   support multiple, remote users, you
>   should start with SQL Server Express
>   Edition and work up the data service
>   family tree.

the runtime supports concurrency on the same machine, not sure about multiple machines accessing the file. in the case the file is stored over a network share, that may not fit the optimal performance profile for ce. i would say go with EE, it's a snap to install with a simple msi.

SSCE Concurrency:

> SSCE allows multiple connections to
>   the same database (.sdf file) from the
>   same application or even multiple
>   applications on the same computer.
>   This gives you more freedom to
>   structure your application as needed,
>   such as allowing the user to continue
>   to interact with data while performing
>   synchronization with a back-end
>   database, or to have multiple
>   applications on the same machine share
>   an SSCE data store. Transactional
>   concurrency locks are made by the
>   database engine to prevent concurrent
>   connections from accessing the same
>   records at the same time. The
>   technical limit on concurrent
>   connections for a single database is
>   256, but 70-80 is a better practical
>   limit from a performance perspective.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb380177%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Micrsoft has published a white paper on this that you should read over and apply to your particular situation.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/4/7/A47B7B0E-976D-4F49-B15D-F02ADE638EBE/Compact_Express_Comparison.doc

The network share apparently precludes Express from being an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you will have less headaches with sql ce as long as you are running everything on one machine. Installing the Express edition on every computer that your app is running on is not good, cumbersome and probably overkill.

Comment: Well, the idea is to have only one database and 3 - 4 clients, so I would only have to install Express once (per customer).

Comment: I think I misread your question. If the application is placed on several machines and you have to put the db on a networkshare, I'd probably go with SQL Express.