# Multi threading in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sql-server-ce, repository-pattern

I have developed a WPF application a unit of work and repository pattern. I am using SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2. My application works fine when using on single thread. But when I am using it on server, user connects through Remote Desktop Connection, and it becomes multi-threaded application which creates problems.

My database is in `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`.

When two users simultaneously fire any transaction with database I am getting following errors:

> Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region.

and

> Database already opened by a different user.

What is the best way to avoid this situation? Or if situation can not be avoided then what can be the best way to handle this exceptions..

Comment: SQL Server CE is a **one-user, local** database - if you need to support multiple concurrent users, you should use the full-blown, server-based SQL Server (Express, Standard - whatever edition - just not Compact)

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you for suggestion but SQL Server Express creates so many complication at the time of installation. But I think I have to use SQL Express only..

Answer (score 0):

As @marc_s has commented, you really should try to use at least `SQL Server Express` or even a higher version to enable multiple concurrent users to successfully access the database from your application simultaneously.

There is a similar question that was asked in the [SQL Server CE in a multi user scenario - is this really, really stupid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992713/sql-server-ce-in-a-multi-user-scenario-is-this-really-really-stupid) post and that post has a good answer with more details that you should take a look at.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but SQL Server Express creates so many complication at the time of installation. But I think I have to use SQL Express only..