# MS SQL Server Compact Edition Multiple User

Tags: c#

I am Developing Winform Application in C# with MS Sqlserver Compact Edition as Database. In Have trouble in multiple User access in this Application. Already i tried Sharing Concept in My Application but getting Error.

Following Error Occured:

> There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using
>   the file.[\JAN-941C126E\Testing_GSm\Debug\New\GSM.sdf]

Any other solution?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992713/sql-server-ce-in-a-multi-user-scenario-is-this-really-really-stupid

Answer (score 0):

Brinda,

**Please make sure that the First connection to the database is not opened in an Exclusive mode.**
Refer below links on how to set the mode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171817.aspx,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171763.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ankit Already I tried SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\New\\GSM.sdf;" + "Mode = Read Write"); but its also not working.. can u give some c# example coding for this

Comment: Did you check the second link?

Comment: S. i Did like this: SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\New\\GSM.sdf;" + "DBPROP_INIT_MODE = DB_MODE_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE;"); error occur :"The type initializer threw an exception."

Comment: can u give some example code for that....